# Проблема с iframe и его высотой на весь экран

Tags: javascript, iframe, height

Прошу помощи у вас, так как долго сижу над этим и не могу никак решить проблему, в интернете ничего не получилось найти. Вот мой код:

```
    <html>
        <iframe
  src="https://carbon.now.sh/embed?bg=rgba(255%2C255%2C255%2C1)&t=monokai&wt=bw&l=javascript&ds=false&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=false&wa=true&pv=0px&ph=0px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=1x&wm=false&code=const%2520pluckDeep%2520%253D%2520key%2520%253D%253E%2520obj%2520%253D%253E%2520key.split('.').reduce((accum%252C%2520key)%2520%253D%253E%2520accum%255Bkey%255D%252C%2520obj)%250A%250Aconst%2520compose%2520%253D%2520(...fns)%2520%253D%253E%2520res%2520%253D%253E%2520fns.reduce((accum%252C%2520next)%2520%253D%253E%2520next(accum)%252C%2520res)%250A%250Aconst%2520unfold%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520go%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520acc)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520const%2520res%2520%253D%2520f(seed)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520res%2520%253F%2520go(f%252C%2520res%255B1%255D%252C%2520acc.concat(%255Bres%255B0%255D%255D))%2520%253A%2520acc%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520go(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520%255B%255D)%250A%257D%250Aconst%2520pluckDeep%2520%253D%2520key%2520%253D%253E%2520obj%2520%253D%253E%2520key.split('.').reduce((accum%252C%2520key)%2520%253D%253E%2520accum%255Bkey%255D%252C%2520obj)%2520const%2520compose%2520%253D%2520(...fns)%2520%253D%253E%2520res%2520%253D%253E%2520fns.reduce((accum%252C%2520next)%2520%253D%253E%2520next(accum)%252C%2520res)%250A"
  style="transform:scale(1); width:100%; height:100%; border:0; overflow:hidden;"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
</iframe>

<h1>Next Content</h1>

<style>
    html, body{
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Я оставил ссылку в iframe что бы, если вам потребовалось, вы могли сами убедиться в этой проблеме. Дело в том, что этот iframe представляет собой сниппет какого-то кода, из сайта [Carbon](https://carbon.now.sh/) и код который вы там написали можно вставить на страницу html с помощью iframe для демонстрации кода. Только когда я вставляю какой-то длинный или же большой код, то у меня на странице появляеться scrollbar, и даже если прописать `iframe{ overflow: hidden; }` он там останеться, но мне убрать его не нужно а просто позволить отображаться iframe в полную длинну по мере сколько кода там находится, и когда ширина экрана меньше, код в iframe как бы смещается вниз, и его польностью видно. Этого я достиг с помощью `html{ height:100% }` и `iframe{ height:100% }` всё хорошо, но теперь он занимает всю длинну страницы, и все элементы после него отображаються в самом низу. Я бы мог это решить сделав например `element{ margin-top: -сколько угодно px;}` но у меня таких фреймов будет не мало, и такое решение не подходит. Как мне сделать так что бы контент не был в самом низу, а красовался сразу внизу после iframe? Буду очень благодарен если кто-то ответит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<iframe
  src="https://carbon.now.sh/embed?bg=rgba(171%2C%20184%2C%20195%2C%201)&t=base16-dark&wt=none&l=text%2Fx-csrc&ds=false&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=false&wa=false&pv=0px&ph=0px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=18px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=1x&wm=false"
  style="width:1024px; height:473px; border:0; margin: 0% 0% -160px -6px"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
</iframe>

<iframe
  src="https://carbon.now.sh/embed?bg=rgba(171%2C%20184%2C%20195%2C%201)&t=base16-dark&wt=none&l=text%2Fx-csrc&ds=false&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=false&wa=false&pv=0px&ph=0px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=18px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=4x&wm=false&code=const%2520pluckDeep%2520%253D%2520key%2520%253D%253E%2520obj%2520%253D%253E%2520key.split(%27.%27).reduce((accum%252C%2520key)%2520%253D%253E%2520accum%255Bkey%255D%252C%2520obj)%250A%250Aconst%2520compose%2520%253D%2520(...fns)%2520%253D%253E%2520res%2520%253D%253E%2520fns.reduce((accum%252C%2520next)%2520%253D%253E%2520next(accum)%252C%2520res)%250A%250Aconst%2520unfold%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520go%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520acc)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520const%2520res%2520%253D%2520f(seed)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520res%2520%253F%2520go(f%252C%2520res%255B1%255D%252C%2520acc.concat(%255Bres%255B0%255D%255D))%2520%253A%2520acc%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520go(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520%255B%255D)%250A%257D%250A%250Aconst%2520pluckDeep%2520%253D%2520key%2520%253D%253E%2520obj%2520%253D%253E%2520key.split(%27.%27).reduce((accum%252C%2520key)%2520%253D%253E%2520accum%255Bkey%255D%252C%2520obj)%250A%250Aconst%2520compose%2520%253D%2520(...fns)%2520%253D%253E%2520res%2520%253D%253E%2520fns.reduce((accum%252C%2520next)%2520%253D%253E%2520next(accum)%252C%2520res)%250A%250Aconst%2520unfold%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520go%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520acc)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520const%2520res%2520%253D%2520f(seed)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520res%2520%253F%2520go(f%252C%2520res%255B1%255D%252C%2520acc.concat(%255Bres%255B0%255D%255D))%2520%253A%2520acc%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520go(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520%255B%255D)%250A%257D"
  style=" width:1024px; height:473px; border:0;  margin-bottom: 12px"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
</iframe>

<iframe
  src="https://carbon.now.sh/embed?bg=rgba(171%2C%20184%2C%20195%2C%201)&t=base16-dark&wt=none&l=text%2Fx-csrc&ds=false&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=false&wa=false&pv=0px&ph=0px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=18px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=1x&wm=false"
  style="width:1024px; height:473px; border:0; margin: 0% 0% -160px -6px"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
</iframe>

<iframe
  src="https://carbon.now.sh/embed?bg=rgba(171%2C%20184%2C%20195%2C%201)&t=base16-dark&wt=none&l=text%2Fx-csrc&ds=false&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=false&wa=false&pv=0px&ph=0px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=18px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=4x&wm=false&code=const%2520pluckDeep%2520%253D%2520key%2520%253D%253E%2520obj%2520%253D%253E%2520key.split(%27.%27).reduce((accum%252C%2520key)%2520%253D%253E%2520accum%255Bkey%255D%252C%2520obj)%250A%250Aconst%2520compose%2520%253D%2520(...fns)%2520%253D%253E%2520res%2520%253D%253E%2520fns.reduce((accum%252C%2520next)%2520%253D%253E%2520next(accum)%252C%2520res)%250A%250Aconst%2520unfold%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520go%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520acc)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520const%2520res%2520%253D%2520f(seed)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520res%2520%253F%2520go(f%252C%2520res%255B1%255D%252C%2520acc.concat(%255Bres%255B0%255D%255D))%2520%253A%2520acc%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520go(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520%255B%255D)%250A%257D%250A%250Aconst%2520pluckDeep%2520%253D%2520key%2520%253D%253E%2520obj%2520%253D%253E%2520key.split(%27.%27).reduce((accum%252C%2520key)%2520%253D%253E%2520accum%255Bkey%255D%252C%2520obj)%250A%250Aconst%2520compose%2520%253D%2520(...fns)%2520%253D%253E%2520res%2520%253D%253E%2520fns.reduce((accum%252C%2520next)%2520%253D%253E%2520next(accum)%252C%2520res)%250A%250Aconst%2520unfold%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520const%2520go%2520%253D%2520(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520acc)%2520%253D%253E%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520const%2520res%2520%253D%2520f(seed)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520res%2520%253F%2520go(f%252C%2520res%255B1%255D%252C%2520acc.concat(%255Bres%255B0%255D%255D))%2520%253A%2520acc%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520go(f%252C%2520seed%252C%2520%255B%255D)%250A%257D"
  style=" width:1024px; height:473px; border:0; "
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin">
</iframe>
```

В данном случае только так margin-bottom: -

И сделал 4х при сохранении фрэйма. Удалил transform:scale(0.7);

Возможно есть более правильное решение. В силу своих минимальных знаний я бы пока поступил так. 
В самом фрейме присутствуют отступы, если бы фрэм был растянут на 100%, то не возникло бы проблем.